# How to swipe multi buttons with one touch

Tags: ios, swift

I have 5 buttons; each allows touchUpInside-action and touchDragOutside-action...as well as doubleTap-action and longPress-action via tapGestureRecognizers.

I would also like to allow user to start a swipe from any UIButton and **Any addition `UIButton` that the swipe touches**, these buttons (including first touch) perform their `@IBAction func Swipe`.

so a continuously swipe like so
[image]
would perform `@IBAction func swipe` for `UIButtons` 1,2,3,4 and 5.

Comment: For a), do you want all buttons the user touched? So like if he dragsOut and hit button2 & button4 then only those IBActions are triggered?

Comment: yes, i edited OP post to clarify

Comment: I see, did you try touchDragInside?

Comment: yes, that would make user have to touch and drag, touch and drag for each button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
// Create an array to hold the buttons you've swiped over
var buttonArray:NSMutableArray!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Make your view's UIPanGestureRecognizer call panGestureMethod:
    // (don't use a UISwipeGestureRecognizer since it's a discrete gesture)
    panGesture.addTarget(self, action: "panGestureMethod:")
}

func panGestureMethod(gesture:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    // Initialize and empty array to hold the buttons at the
    // start of the gesture 
    if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
        buttonArray = NSMutableArray()
    }

    // Get the gesture's point location within its view
    // (This answer assumes the gesture and the buttons are
    // within the same view, ex. the gesture is attached to
    // the view controller's superview and the buttons are within
    // that same superview.)
    let pointInView = gesture.locationInView(gesture.view)

    // For each button, if the gesture is within the button and
    // the button hasn't yet been added to the array, add it to the
    // array. (This example uses 4 buttons instead of 9 for simplicity's
    // sake
    if !buttonArray.containsObject(button1) && CGRectContainsPoint(button1.frame, pointInView){
        buttonArray.addObject(button1)
    }
    else if !buttonArray.containsObject(button2) && CGRectContainsPoint(button2.frame, pointInView){
        buttonArray.addObject(button2)
    }
    else if !buttonArray.containsObject(button3) && CGRectContainsPoint(button3.frame, pointInView){
        buttonArray.addObject(button3)
    }
    else if !buttonArray.containsObject(button4) && CGRectContainsPoint(button4.frame, pointInView){
        buttonArray.addObject(button4)
    }

    // Once the gesture ends, trigger the buttons within the
    // array using whatever control event would otherwise trigger
    // the button's method.
    if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended && buttonArray.count > 0 {
        for button in buttonArray {
            (button as UIButton).sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        }
    }
}
```

(Edit: Here are a few answers I've written in the past explaining what I meant by `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` being a discrete gesture: [stackoverflow.com/a/27072281/2274694](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27072281/2274694), [stackoverflow.com/a/25253902/2274694](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25253902/2274694))

Comment: That is so awesome‼‼ Ty so much. However I am confused on one concept here.  `if !buttonArray.containsObject(button1)` is the "!" mean "does not(contain)"? because the way i read this otherwise its saying if `button1` is in `buttonArray`, add `button1` to `buttonArray`.×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes

Comment: @Dustin Yes, it means does not contain.

Comment: @Dustin No worries. :)

Comment: @Lyndsey_Scott while i have you on the line, can I ask you what it means that UISwipeGestureRecognizer is a **"discrete"** gesture. I did notice early that i couldn't use it to create a segue like other gestures.

Comment: @Dustin Here are a couple answers I've written to explain: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27072281/2274694, http://stackoverflow.com/a/25253902/2274694