# Create multi touch event on single swipe

Tags: ios, uibutton, touch, swipe

I have four button on single view I want to swipe a finger on all button then all button actions are fired, how can i do?

Comment: Please add some code that you have written so far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172160/how-to-swipe-multi-buttons-with-one-touch

Comment: i want  like this link but this code is not proper work for me.

Answer (score 0):

swipe gesture can not recognize the button on your view is pressed or not. so using swipe over the button you can not call its ibAction.