# How would I make a UiPanGestureRecognizer check if the finger is in the buttons frame?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to make an app where the user could drag a finger on top of multiple buttons and get some actions for each button.

There was [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172160/how-to-swipe-multi-buttons-with-one-touch) from a while back but when I tried to use `CGRectContainsPoint(button.frame, point)` it said it was replaced with `button.frame.contains(point)` but this didn’t seem to work for me. [Here is a link to the Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWmqT.png)

What I have done so far:

```
var buttonArray:NSMutableArray!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGestureMethod(_:)))
    a1.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    a2.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
}
@objc func panGestureMethod(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    
    
    if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {
        buttonArray = NSMutableArray()
    }
    
    let pointInView = gesture.location(in: gesture.view)
    
    if !buttonArray.contains(a1!) && a1.frame.contains(pointInView) {
        buttonArray.add(a1!)
        a1Tapped(a1)
    }
    else if !buttonArray.contains(a2!) && a2.frame.contains(pointInView) {
        buttonArray.add(a2!)
        a2Tapped(a2)
    }
```

The code did run fine but when I tried to activate the drag nothing happened. Any tips?

Comment: Please add code samples of what you have until now (as short as possible) & state what you have tried an why it failed (e.g. errors).

Comment: OK, I added some code and a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want behavior similar to the system keyboard I assume? `CGRectContainsPoint` is not deprecated: See [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1456316-cgrectcontainspoint). In Swift it's written like `frame.contains()`.

When dealing with rects and points you have to make sure both are translated to the same coordinate system first. To do so you can use the convert to/from methods on UIView: See ([the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622504-convert)).

In your case smth. like the following should work (first translate button frames, then check if the point is inside):

```swift
func touchedButtonForGestureRecognizer(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> UIView? {
    let pointInView = gesture.location(in: gesture.view)
    for (button in buttonArray) {
        let rect = gesture.view.convert(button.frame from:button.superview)
        if (rect.contains(pointInView)) {
          return button
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Yes I want something like the keyboard but I said wrong in the question. It is not deprecated, it wanted me to replace it with `button.frame.contains(point)`. Do you know a Swift version of this code?

Comment: I updated my answer to focus on the rect math & translated it to swift. Hope that helps. You probably want to learn reading objc too though, it is easy to translate it to swift.

Comment: Thanks! I am away from my Mac atm but i will check when i get back!! Thanks for all the help and your time!!

Comment: I think i forgot to do `let rect = gesture.view.convert(button.frame from:button.superview)`

Comment: I have now tried it and it works perfectly!! I would have never gotten this working without you!! Thank you!!!!!